# Trying to compare two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

So the problem I've been given is this:
List of all course numbers and course description and if the course has a prerequisites, the prerequisite’s course name and number.

The table includes course_no, description (name of the course), cost, prerequisites. I know I need to compare the prerequisites to the course_no since the prerequisites contains the course_no for the course the student must have completed.

I cannot for the life of me figure out the subquery in order to compare to the two and return the description of the prerequisite course.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
select Course_No,course_Name,
isnull(prerequisite_course_name,'No Prerequisite') as prerequisite_course_name,
isnull(prerequisite_course_no,'No Prerequisite')as prerequisite_course_no 
from course A 
left join Course_Prerequisite B on A.Course_no = B.Course_No
```

Does this help?

Comment: yes and no. so if I got course A and course B, I need to compare a.prerequisite to b.course_no and then output b.description as the description for a.prerequisite

Comment: I suppose you have two table, Course and Course_Prerequisite. Then you join the two table to get description. Isnt that all the requirement? Anyway you have any sample format of tables you have and output you expected?

Comment: it's just one table course with the columns course_no, description, cost and prerequisite

Comment: Can you provide sample of output you wanna see? I cant imagine what it

Comment: Course_no    Description                PreReq     Description
25           Intro to Programming       140        Structured Analysis

That's what I'm looking for. So the preqreq # and description match, prereq is a course_no

Comment: I got it with this

select C.course_no, C.description, P.prerequisite, P.description
from course C join course P on C.course_no = P.PREREQUISITE